# Count duplicates in dictionary by specific keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I need to count duplicates by specific keys.
For example:

```
[
   {'name': 'John', 'age': 10, 'country': 'USA', 'height': 185}, 
   {'name': 'John', 'age': 10, 'country': 'Canada', 'height': 185}, 
   {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 10, 'country': 'USA', 'height': 180},
   {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 10, 'country': 'Canada', 'height': 180},
   {'name': 'Doe', 'age': 15, 'country': 'Canada', 'height': 185}
]
```

If will specify '**age**' and '**country**' it should return

```
[  
   {
      'age': 10,
      'country': 'USA',
      'count': 2 
   },
   {
      'age': 10,
      'country': 'Canada',
      'count': 2 
   },
   {
      'age': 15,
      'country': 'Canada',
      'count': 1
   }
]
```

Or if I will specify '**name**' and '**height**':

```
[  
   {
      'name': 'John',
      'height': 185,
      'count': 2 
   },
   {
      'name': 'Mark',
      'height': 180,
      'count': 2 
   },
   {
      'name': 'Doe',
      'heigth': 185,
      'count': 1
   }
]
```

Maybe there is a way to implement this by Counter?

Comment: what have you tried and what problem you have faced ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) list:

```
>>> data = [
   {'name': 'John', 'age': 10, 'country': 'USA', 'height': 185}, 
   {'name': 'John', 'age': 10, 'country': 'Canada', 'height': 185}, 
   {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 10, 'country': 'USA', 'height': 180},
   {'name': 'Mark', 'age': 10, 'country': 'Canada', 'height': 180},
   {'name': 'Doe', 'age': 15, 'country': 'Canada', 'height': 185}
]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> key = 'age', 'country'
>>> list_sorter = lambda x: tuple(x[k] for k in key)
>>> grouper = lambda x: tuple(x[k] for k in key)
>>> result = [
        {**dict(zip(key, k)), 'count': len([*g])} 
         for k, g in 
         groupby(sorted(data, key=list_sorter), grouper)
    ]
>>> result

[{'age': 10, 'country': 'Canada', 'count': 2},
 {'age': 10, 'country': 'USA', 'count': 2},
 {'age': 15, 'country': 'Canada', 'count': 1}]

>>> key = 'name', 'height'
>>> result = [
        {**dict(zip(key, k)), 'count': len([*g])} 
         for k, g in 
         groupby(sorted(data, key=list_sorter), grouper)
    ]

>>> result

[{'name': 'Doe', 'height': 185, 'count': 1},
 {'name': 'John', 'height': 185, 'count': 2},
 {'name': 'Mark', 'height': 180, 'count': 2}]
```

If you use `pandas` then you can use, [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`pandas.groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), [`pandas.Series.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html), [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and finally [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient='records'`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.groupby(list(key)).size().to_frame('count').reset_index().to_dict('records')

[{'name': 'Doe', 'height': 185, 'count': 1},
 {'name': 'John', 'height': 185, 'count': 2},
 {'name': 'Mark', 'height': 180, 'count': 2}]
```